# mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10 libcrypto.so.10

Tags: mongodb, openssl, libssl, libcrypto

**Problem**

I downloaded the `mongodb 3.0.7` tar files. Then I added the bin directory to my path:

```
export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH
```

Then when I run the mongodb server:

```
mongod --fork --logpath "/home/me/mongolog" --dbpath "/home/me/data"
```

I get this error:

```
mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**What I did**

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339364/libssl-so-10-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory). In brief I updated my openssl:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
```

and then:

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

but it says that it cannot find `libssl.so.10` and `libcrypto.so.10`. I don't know what to do!

Comment: I don't have a (good) answer for you, but this happened to me today when I installed the latest version of Mongo on an old host (Cent 5). I worked around it by installing an older version that I knew to work. I suspect Mongo has introduced a dependency on a newer (maybe post-heartbleed?) version of Openssl.

Comment: @Fopedush Ohh you meant you installed an older version of mongo? I think it should have some approach for installing it!

Comment: I agree, there _should_ be a straightforward way of installing the latest mongo on an older host. Unfortunately I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Just start over from [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

If you don't want 3.2, do not

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Specify the version for all the individual components in the next step.

OR you can copy the correct version link from [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production).

You will need to

```
cd /Downloads 
wget wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-correct-version.tgz
tar -zxvf mongodb-correct-version.tgz
```

You should see all the executables. 
Make sure /usr/local/bin is in your PATH

```
echo $PATH
```

Create a symbolic link for the mongod server and check the version.

```
sudo ln -s ~/Downloads/mongodb-correct-version/bin/mongod /usr/local/sbin/bin/mongod
mongod --version
```

Now create a symbolic link for the shell and check the version.

```
sudo ln -s ~/Downloads/mongodb-correct-version/bin/mongo /usr/local/bin/mongo
mongo --version
```

Create a directory path for the server.

```
mkdir ~/data
mkdir ~/data/db
```

Start the server and let it run from a separate terminal than the shell.

```
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db/
```

It should be listening on port 27017. 
In a new terminal, start mongo.

```
mongo
```

Comment: I knew that. There is a limited access to internet for this server I'm working on. Thank you by the way. I've solved this solution but I couldn't find a time to write it here. I'll do it as soon as possible.

Comment: I just added details. This is a common issue.

Comment: @Edward Sorry for late answer. Just follow this solution it have to work.

Answer (score 7):

Seems that mongo is expecting libssl files in `/usr/lib/`:

```
  sudo cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
  sudo cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
```

Answer (score 4):

Check your server version, your system may be centos, but downloaded the ubuntu version of the mongodb. Download again just fine

`wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.10.tgz`

Comment: I've got that error on Centos 8 with `mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.6.14.tgz`; plain Linux package `mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.6.14.tgz` worked fine.  Previously I installed without any problem `mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.4.9.tgz` on Centos 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MongoDB v3.4.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have the same issue:

```
mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpmibs.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To FIX it, I had to install snmp with `apt-get`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install snmp
```

Hope this helps someone somewhere out there beneath the pale moonlight... <8,_,)-----

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, even after following instructions below. But my problem was solved when I tried `sudo mongo`

Comment: This is probably because your `root` has a different environment paths. I don't think this would solve the problem in general.

Answer (score 0):

i had this same problem and what i did was

1. created `/data/db` in the root folder(i use a Linux distro)
2. then, `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db/`
3. then, `mongo`

i hope this helps anyone facing the same problem in future

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar issue like yours. The fix is that --dbpath should point to an existing directory

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20 (Focal Fossa), none of the solutions looked anyhow decent (with no ugly hacks) nor were working.

Got it perfectly fine with this tutorial from DigitalOcean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04

---

Or the tutorial from the official documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongocli/master/install/

Meanwhile the commands given into the UI while creating a cluster were totally wrong.