# How to run MongoDB in Anaconda?

Tags: mongodb, anaconda

I'm using the Anaconda package manager, and I installed the `mongodb` package in Anaconda using the `conda install mongodb` command. But when I run `mongo` to start the Mongo shell, I get an error as follows:

```
mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693635/mongod-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-10-libcrypto-so-10 Try this link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try re-installing the latest version of MongoDB through the Anaconda package manager

```
conda install -c anaconda mongodb=3.3.9
```

Seed details in the [Anaconda documentation](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mongodb)

Comment: This version is only available for os x right now :( https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mongodb/files